# Extending a switch mode power supply controller IC to work under higher input voltages

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck

I have a [AP6502](http://www.diodes.com/datasheets/AP6502.pdf) IC, which is a cheap DC-DC buck converter. It converts a DC voltage in the level of 4.7V-18V to a DC voltage of 0.925V-16V. I works under 2A current maximum.

[image]
Example Usage of AP6502 given in its datasheet.

But, I have a much higher DC voltage level; it goes up to 100V. The output voltage will be 18V. And I want to flow 20A current at maximum. I want to extend/improve the example circuit above, so that this IC would work under higher voltages.

My attempt on this is the circuit below:

[image]

Is it possible to do this kind of extension? If yes, would my circuit work, is my solution correct? If my circuit is wrong, what is the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

No this won't work for a few reasons. Firstly the simple reasons: -

---

Original answer #1 was incorrect so deleted and answer 2 edited

1. First answer deleted
2. Driving the FET with the collector of a BJT is not good for the speed of the pulses. The collector resistor has to discharge gate capacitance and this will cause gross inefficiences.
3. The gate-source region will be destroyed by too much voltage due to the BJT pulling it down to ground.

The more complex reason: -

1. Even if you could cure the problems above there is the issue of loop
   stability which I'm afraid will kill-off this idea completely. You
   now have introduced two gain stages (cascaded) into the feedback
   system of the basic chip and this will never stabilize correctly -
   it'll sing and ring and oscillate.

> what is the correct way of doing it?

Recommendation - keep the chip in the draw and find a proper switcher that can do the job.